# Separator for Google API “Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)”

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine

Google API asks for

```
Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites)
```

What is the separator for multiple sites? Say, is it

```
*/example.com/*;*.mysite.com/*
*/example.com/*,*.mysite.com/*
*/example.com/* *.mysite.com/*
```

or how do I indicate multiple referrers here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type one URL and click outside the field, a new field appears where you can type another URL.